# Export single page PDF from Libre Office Draw?

Tags: 18.04, libreoffice

I would like to export from a multi page Libre Office Draw file arbitrarily single or more pages into a PDF. How do I do that?

LibreOffice version is 6.0.7.3 on a Ubuntu 18.04, which is completely operational and all circuits are functioning perfectly.

Comment: I usually use print, select the page or range of pages and then print to file.

Comment: The export dialog of 6.1.4.2 allows to select pages. If that is not yet possible in your version, then know that the feature is coming. Lacking the feature, you still can  split out a page from the PDF using a dedicated tool such as qpdf or pdftk. And indeed, using "print" may also be a valid option.

Comment: @vanadium Please define selected. I selected two pages and hit the File>Export as PDF Dialog --> selected Pages Radio button. Result is ALL pages exported. That's not a very smart exporter module.

Comment: On 6.1.4.2, the "Export to PDF" dialog contains a section "range", where one can set which pages to include in the exported PDF.